# Nginx How to redirect HTTP non-www to HTTPS www with a single redirect?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, www

I'm redirecting incoming HTTP traffic on port 80 to HTTPS on port 443. There, I'm redirecting non-www to www:

http://example.com -> https://example.com --> https://www.example.com

It seems google pagespeed insights counts this as "multiple redirects". It also does seem introduce 300-400ms latency between each redirect.

Is there any way to do a redirect in one step for all scenarios?

1. HTTP non-www -> HTTPS www
2. HTTP www -> HTTPS www
3. HTTPS non-www -> HTTPS www
4. HTTPS www -> HTTPS www

My config file below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.js index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        ssl_certificate /ssl/example.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /ssl/example.com.key;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /wordpress {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.js index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /ssl/example.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /ssl/example.com.key;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /wordpress {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your configuration , you can :

- you can catch multiple name **example.com** and **www.example.com**
- you can redirect directly to **www.example.com**

Example of all redirect configuration :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com  www.example.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/example.com.key;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com ;

    # HERE you push all you configuration for HTTPS://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM

    #.../.../

}
```

Comment: thanks. I realized I asked a pretty dumb question lol. All I needed to do was to redirect in my port 80 server block directly to `https://www`.